# Line spacing in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

Is there a way to increase the line spacing in Google Sheets, not the cell padding? I'm referring to the space between the lines in a paragraph that's inside a cell. If not, is there an addon that can do it? See the pic:

[image]

Comment: Welcome. No there isn't. Your only alternative is to [create paragraphs/new lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSc3C.png).

Comment: Please show what you tried and add brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. NOTE: Question asking for software recommendations are off-topic here, try [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it's possible, except maybe with a script. If you know a little bit of Javascript you might be able to do it programmatically via the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api). Hope that helps!